# using a time delay in javascript(specific circumstance)

Tags: javascript, methods, time, delay

I found a sample code snippet on this site for a js time delay. When I run the js debug (after clicking a button) everything works fine. Each update is shown on the page after the proper delay. But when I remove debug and let the script run(after clicking a button), it is as if it runs all the code and only gives the last update. I have tried also the function setTimeout(), but the same thing happens. When I test the time delay code by itself (with no other code) it works fine.

Does this have anything to do with the asynchronous nature of javascript? If other people are using the time delay code, I must be missing something...what might that be?

**code below:**

> id="lottoNbr" style="margin-left:40px;" onclick="getRandom(8,2)" alt="dollar >signs"> 
>  click

click event above, javascript below:

```
function getRandom(y1, z1) {
      var y2=y1; //this is the maximum random number generated
      var z2 = z1; // determined which game is being played
      var choice, choice1;
      var i, count;

      //f = setInterval(rNbr,50);
       /* pick 10 numbers from 1 to 9 slowly and return the last value to the screen three times*/
      function rNbr() {
          choice = 1 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * y2)); 
          choice1 = choice.toString();
          gameName();
      }  

      function sleep(milliseconds) {
        const date = Date.now();
        let currentDate = null;
        do {
          currentDate = Date.now();
        } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
      }
      function gameName() {
        switch(z2) {
            //case 2 means big three game, case 3 meand giant 4 game, etc
            case 2:
              if (i == 0) {
                document.getElementById("3lottoNbr1").innerHTML = choice1;
              } else if (i == 1) {
                document.getElementById("3lottoNbr2").innerHTML = choice1;
              } else {
                document.getElementById("3lottoNbr3").innerHTML = choice1;
              }
              break;
            case 3: //giant 4
              if (i == 0) {
                document.getElementById("4lottoNbr1").innerHTML = choice1;
              } else if (i == 1) {
                document.getElementById("4lottoNbr2").innerHTML = choice1;
              } else if (i == 1) {
                document.getElementById("4lottoNbr3").innerHTML = choice1;
              } else {
                document.getElementById("4lottoNbr4").innerHTML = choice1;
              }
              break;

        }

      }

      generate random numbers spin style in each of the game windows
      setTimeout(rNbr, 500);
      for(i=0; i<=z2; i++) {
        for(count = 0; count <= 2; count++) {
          rNbr();
          document.getElementById("proof").innerHTML = count;
          sleep(2000);
        }
        sleep(1000);
      }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: There is no global asynchronous nature to javascript.

Comment: Also your question is starting a discussion about logic you have written, but you have not provided that logic for us to see.  There's no way for us to guess at what logic you have written to be able to help.  You need to provide specifics, potentially in the form of a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, please share your code.

Comment: sorry, trying not to get messy. no code on purpose.

Comment: Code in this situation is required.  You're not asking about how to use a standardized method correctly.  You are saying you wrote logic and it's not behaving like you expect it to.  We have no idea what that custom logic is.  We cannot help you with things we do not know exist.

Comment: added code to help with question.

Answer (score 0):

found this hint on the site:

> The PHP part is executed only once on page load. Take a look at the source code >(right click on the page, "show source code"), you'll see the value assigned >statically, since it's generated with PHP before the page is loaded into the browser. >Keep in mind that Javascript and PHP are executed in separated contexts : PHP > >server side, Javascript > client side.
>
> A little help to resolve your problem : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/.

add window.addEventListener("onload", f()); **after the page is loaded** add onloaded event listener and function to be performed.  Not during the body loaded event.